# How to test STDIN read error

Tags: linux, assembly, stdin

I have a `Linux` program (currently in assembly) that has a check: if a read from `STDIN` failed, show an error message. The problem is that I do not know how to test this condition, how to execute the program so that it will fail reading from STDIN. IT must be run without STDIn or STDIN couldbe closed some how before the program starts?

Comment: Use the `read` system call. Read its documentation to see how errors are communicated.

Comment: Uhm, my question is not how to test the read syscall result from my program. I already have this test implemented. I need to test teh program and provide it a failed stdin and see if my implemented test works properly.

Comment: I see; never mind then, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: As I understand the question, he wants to deliberately cause an error on `sys_read` from `stdin` to test his error handler. I don't know the answer. Unplug the keyboard? Perhaps read into an invalid buffer address (`ecx` or `rsi`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can close the file descriptor, that will trigger an error. Test using `bash`:

```
$ strace ./a.out 0<&-
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=4012 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
read(0, 0xffe13fec, 1)                  = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

You can also provoke other errors that are listed in the man page, such as:

```
$ strace ./a.out 0</tmp
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 32 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=4056 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
read(0, 0xffed5c0c, 1)                  = -1 EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

Comment: I do not understand how it works and what is the weird output but obviously it woks!

Comment: `./a.out 0<&-` is enough

Comment: `strace` is a system call tracer, I used it to show that `read` returns an error code.